# Exception raised while integrating Twilo sdk to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am integrating Twilo sdk to my iPhone app.

> NSString *urlString=@"urlstring";

```
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request startSynchronous];

    NSString *response=[request responseString];

    NSLog(@"Response:%@",response);

    NSDictionary *dict=[response JSONValue];

    NSMutableString *capabilityToken=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"message"]];

    device = [[TCDevice alloc] initWithCapabilityToken:capabilityToken delegate:nil];
```

I am getting response as

> {"message":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJBQzYwYTFlOTMxOTI5NmFhNmFlZDcwZjhkYjZhMTQyNGJmIiwiZXhwIjoxMzM3NzU5MTA3LCJzY29wZSI6InNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDpvdXRnb2luZz9hcHBTaWQ9QVAxODRlNTE3YzZmN2EyZGI5NTkwMzM5N2I3NWRkMDliMSJ9.fXjQhBaXu3OlN_zXZIvSkoElphtQuW1QnNSbmUzfsSc"}

Assigning that string to TCDevice object while initializing I am getting following exception.

> -[__NSCFString PJSTRString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x77a21d0

Can anyone please help me the reason for this exception and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the flags '-ObjC -all_load' to the "Other Linker Flags" in your target's Build Settings